# Which socket option do I need to receive ICMP errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I've made a socket in python 3 using the code below:

```
tracesocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.getprotobyname('icmp'))
```

And now I need to edit the options for it to accept ICMP errors. However, I cannot find any documentation of the options that these sockets have, so I do not know what option I have to fix. What are the options here that I have to update here?

Comment: I think that should receive all ICMP messages, which includes errors. I don't think you need a special otion.

Comment: @Barmar It's not receiving errrors

Comment: This may be because the kernel automatically processes errors itself, it doesn't make them available to raw sockets. You'll probably need to use PCAP.

Comment: @Barmar What is PCAP?

Comment: The packet capture library, used by tools like Wireshark and tcpdump.